# Is there any way to know why NSHFSTypeOfFile fails?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, foundation

I am having the following code to check the file type of a file in mac:

```
OSType GetFileTypeFromPath( const std::string & inFilePath )
{
    NSString * pathToFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:inFilePath.data()
                                                     length:inFilePath.size() * sizeof(char)
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *fileType =  NSHFSTypeOfFile( pathToFile );
    return NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType( fileType );;
}
```

I found the function, 'NSHFSTypeOfFile', in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode

The functions returns me the result for some file. I am interested in pdf files alone. For some pdf files it works fine but for others the string returned by the function in nil. I don't know whether it is anything wrong with the file or the filepath I am providing (like encoding. Is there any way to get the reason for the function `NSHFSTypeOfFile` to fail?

Comment: Most files do not have a Macintosh file type anymore. Try "GetFileInfo yourfile.pdf" (if the developer tools are installed).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The GetFileInfo works fine.